# Test subdomains in staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, subdomain, puma

I'm using rails 6 with puma server and nginx as a web server. I'm creating a project that I would like to have a subdomain `subdomain.my-domain.com`. I have created a staging environment on domain `staging.my-domain.com`. How can I test the subdomains of the project on the staging environment.
I was thinking something like `subdomain.staging.my-domain.com` but what changes should I do to the nginx conf file and the rails environment conf file?

Comment: More server sections with in your nginx config with the `server_name subdomain.staging.my-domain.com`

Comment: Or add the test domains to the relevant `server_name` so each `server` block can be accessed using either the production domain name or the staging domain name. E.g. `server_name app.example.com app.staging.example.com;`

Answer (score 0):

By default the `config.action_dispatch.tld_length` value is `1`. If you ask for the domain `subdomain.staging.my-domain.com`, on the rails app the `request.subdomain` value is `subdomain.staging`. In order for rails to recognise the correct subdomain, in our case `subdomain`, I added in my environment staging config file the line `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2`

Comment: https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/03/04/building-a-rails-app-with-multiple-subdomains.html